# Retrieving the "Version" attribute of an OSX Application file via Bash

Tags: macos, bash, script, metadata

I was initially attempting to do this in Java using the UserDefinedFileAttributeView class but it turns out that is only available on Windows computers (This is being run on OSX)

So I switched gears with the hope that retrieving the information via a script would be the simpler route but it seems to not be as straight forward as I expected.

How would one go about retrieving an Application file's version number (file attribute) using Bash?

I've already looked into `stat` but that only returns the basic file information.
I also looked into `xattr` but I couldn't get that to return the "Version" attribute.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where do you think this information is being stored? Please post an example.

Comment: Your Q lacks detail. Have your read, understood, and tried to write an appropriate "MCVE" -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? Good luck.

Comment: To add to other comments, it's difficult to answer the question as asked, the best thing to do would be take a step back and state why you are trying to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @CodeGnome The version number is easily seen by right clicking a file in OS X and viewing its "info"  not sure how much more detail is needed. I'm that familiar with Bash scripting and I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve this value via a Bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the Version of an Application, which is what's shown in the Finder Get Info dialog box, then use this:

```
plutil -p /Applications/<Application Name>.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep CFBundleShortVersionString
```

This will show you the version information.

For more information see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127566) answer.

Comment: Thank you this also worked perfectly. I also posted an alternative below.

Comment: Thank you, for the benefit of anybody coming across this question I'd suggest updating the question to clarify you're not trying to get the version of a file from the filesystem but the version of an OSX application. If you look at the finder info for an arbitrary file on the filesystem you'll see that it doesn't have a version.

Comment: I've updated my question appropriately.  I wasn't familiar with the version attribute but I know see what you are saying. It was an oversight on my part

Comment: The "-p" argument to plutil is not valid for some older versions of OS X.  You can accomplish the same thing with `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleShortVersionString" /Applications/<APPLICATION NAME>.app/Contents/Info.plist`, which will just print the value without the need to grep anything.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `defaults` to fetch specific keys:

```
VERSION=$(defaults read /Applications/AppName.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleShortVersionString)
echo $VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept digging around and it looks like one possible solution is to use `mdls` , with the attribute 'kMDItemVersion'.

Example:

```
Applications: user$ mdls -name kMDItemVersion Xcode.app
kMDItemVersion = "7.2"
```

If anyone else needs this the documentation is here: [mdls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdls.1.html)

Answer (score -1):

Generally Linux does not support a file version attribute. However you can use `mimetype` utility to access file extension and type...

example

```
mimetype -d path_to_my_file
```

Comment: I am referring to the "Version" tag not File Versioning it self.

Comment: Linux doesn't have that...linux is a little different from WIndows...I have been using linux for years now..I am not aware of that..my apologies...

Comment: He's asking about OSX (as per the parenthetical remark in the first paragraph).

Comment: have you tried the mimetype utility in linux?..I have explored some of the basic parameter arguments but no luck....